# how to show text while typing in textarea in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

i looking for a way to preview  the text while im typing in a textarea in jquery

exactly what u are using for Stackoverflow ,

Comment: Do you mean a 'live-preview' function?

Comment: i think so , im looking for a function to do exactly like SOF's "Ask question " section

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#someTextBox').keyup(function(){
      $('#target').html($(this).val());
    });
  });
</script>

<textarea id="someTextBox"></textarea>
<div id="target"></div>
```

As you type text in the `<textarea>`, the text should be duplicated in the HTML of the `<div>`.

Comment: +1. You should promote jQuery's shorthand document ready with `$(function(){...});`

Comment: @Justin, either use `this.value` or `$(this).val()`.

Comment: @David Murdoch, I am not so sure about that.
Its an old debate. It is much more readable even if its a bit longer way

Comment: eh, usually document ready is at the very top the of the script element/file and I find that readability isn't ever an issue. But if you are burying `$(document).ready(...)` within other code for some odd reason I totally agree with you.

Comment: hey guys i need to use my php function to show slugged title  how can i use php function between jquery codes ?