# Show text while typing

Tags: jquery

I thought this one was a simple one but I wasn't able to find anything out there, except [one post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684402/how-to-show-text-while-typing-in-textarea-in-jquery) on STO.

Problem is the code doesn't work. I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzea/FjNzS/) so you can see it for yourself.

Here is the code from the fiddle:

```
$('#someTextBox').keyup(function() {
    $('#target').html(this.val());
});
```

However, my HTML is a bit different than the example:

```
<textarea name="comment-box" id="comment-box" class="required"></textarea>
...
<p id="comment-preview"></p>
```

All I need help with is a way to display what's being typed on the `textarea` on the `"comment-preview"` container.

Any help guiding me on this one is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change `this.val()` to `$(this).val()`

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/FjNzS/1/

`.val` is a jQuery function and can be accessed from jQuery object. Inside the handler, `this` is DOM object and so you need to wrap it with `$()` to make it a jQuery object.

Comment: Oh! There was a typo in the example. Explanation was thorough plus the working example, thanks a lot for that.

Answer (score 5):

You can either use `$(this).val()` or `this.value`, but `this.val()` is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this code with `.on()`:

```
$('#someTextBox').on('keyup', function(){
    $('#target').html($(this).val());
});
```

Exemple http://jsfiddle.net/FjNzS/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#comment-box").keyup(function() {
    $("#comment-preview").text($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: `.text()` will just get you the initial value.. you should use `.val` or `this.value`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964646/textarea-elem-val-vs-elem-text

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how I'm using it now. Gave you an upvote. Thanks.