# Change text in the anchor tag while typing in text input in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, this sounds easy, but I'm having problems trying to identify the anchor tag. The HTML block repeats itself.

```
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#q1">
     Question 1
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="q1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputQ1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Question</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputQ1" placeholder="e.g How was our service?">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I got the answer I need over here
[how to show text while typing in textarea in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684402/how-to-show-text-while-typing-in-textarea-in-jquery)

What I need to know is, how do I make it so that the text in the anchor tag changes? I don't want to put in an ID for all of them. I should be using parent() and siblings(), right?

Comment: so what do you want to do? when you type in the text field you want to change the title to be same as the text field content?

Comment: @ArunPJohny yeap, that is correct :)

Comment: You could replace the id with a class name, element, data-attribute ..etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.panel-body input').keyup(function(){
        $(this).closest('.panel-collapse').prev('.panel-heading').find('a').text(this.value)
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jftCP/)

Note: To be more specific I might add an additional class as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jftCP/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with keyup and html:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#text").keyup(function(){

        $("#q1").html($(this).val());

    });

});
```

Where `#text` is the textarea and `#q1` is the anchor:

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUVY2/2/)

Comment: the block repeats itelf

Comment: @ArunPJohny what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('#inputQ1').keyup(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('#q1').prev().find('a').html($this.val());
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sPKaE/)**

Answer (score 1):

I think the best (because the logic) if you could create a parent around this code (if you can)

```
<div class="parent">
  <h4>
    <a>...</a>
  </h4>
  <div>
     <input>
  </div>
</div>
```

in the event `$(this)` is your input

you can use `$(this).closest('parent').find('a')` to find the  for the

Answer (score 0):

Try using anchor parent:

```
$('.panel-title a').text( /* textarea text */ );
```

Comment: @InYourDreamz How do you know what element you wish to change?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.panel-title a').text( 'new text' );
```